# How to get the parameters for a stored procedure using Enterprise library with generic database

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, enterprise-library-4.1

When i use this, i get the following exception

```
Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase. You must specify the parameters explicitly, or configure the connection to use a type deriving from Database that supports parameter discovery.
```

Is there a right way other than this procedure.

**EDIT**

```
Database db = CustomDbFactory.CreateDataBase(connStrName); 
DbCommand command = db.DbProviderFactory.CreateCommand(); 
command.CommandText = @spName; 
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
db.DiscoverParameters(command); 
...
```

Comment: if you provide the code and configurations we may be able to help

Comment: please edit your original post and provide the code and configuration there. placing it in the comments isn't helpful.

Comment: @JasonMeckley: Done editing the question to add the code for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is supported only the `SqlDatabase` objects only. Hence, instead of calling the `DiscoverParameters` on a `GenericDatabase`, I had to call it from a `SqlDatabase`.. Specifics Issue.