# c# enterprise library 5 odbc connection issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, odbc, enterprise-library

When I call this method from another class I get an exception:

```
public DataSet getDataSet(String storedProcedureName, params object[] values)
{
     Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("myDSN");
     return db.ExecuteDataSet(storedProcedureName, values); // This line fails
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase. You must specify the parameters explicitly, or configure the connection to use a type deriving from Database that supports parameter discovery.

But if I use this code and the stored procedure has no parameters it works:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(CommandType commandType, string storedProcedureName)
{
     Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("myDSN");
     return db.ExecuteDataSet(commandType, storedProcedureName);
}
```

So, what should I do to make the first method work?
I'm using visual studio community 2015, sql server 2008 R2 express, enterprise library 5 and .net framework 4.5.2 in my project.

Comment: can you try hardcoding the parameter like this db.ExecuteDataSet(storedProcedureName, "value1", "value2");?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the same error.

Comment: i see, the problem is you're using oracle and not sql server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590524/how-to-get-the-parameters-for-a-stored-procedure-using-enterprise-library-with-g

Comment: coincidentally the database is sql server 2008 r2. I have updated the question information

Comment: I found a solution using SqlDatabase object instead of Database object. Thanks for the link!.